# PDOException does not show my sql table

Tags: 7, blocks

Hello Every body I have an SQL Query to DB

```
function darkSiteContent($delta){
     switch ($delta) {
     //SQL Query to find the title , nid of the node and its body
     case 'popup_dark_screen':
      $result = db_query("
        SELECT n.title , n.nid , b.body_value
        FROM {dot_node} as n , {dot_field_revision_body} as b , {dot_node_type} as t
        WHERE t.type = 'dark_sit' AND n.type = t.type and b.bundle = t.type 
        order by n.title desc LIMIT 1
        ");
        $items = array();
        foreach ($result as $row) {
        print_r($row);
        $items[] = l(t($row->title, 'node/' . $row->nid )).'
'.$row->body_value;
        }
      return array('#markup' => theme('item_list', array('items' => $items)));
      break;
    }

}
```

But it show this error

```
PDOException: SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'APIG01JO2012039.dot_dot_node' doesn't exist: SELECT n.title , n.nid , b.body_value FROM {dot_node} as n , {dot_field_revision_body} as b , {dot_node_type} as t WHERE t.type = 'dark_sit' AND n.type = t.type and b.bundle = t.type order by n.title desc LIMIT 1 ; Array ( ) in darkSiteContent() (line 71 of C:\AppServ\www\APIG01JO2012039\sites\all\modules\darksite\darksite.module).
```

I am sure of my table name but it still show this error

Comment: try giving the table name as just node instead of dot_node

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using database with in {} you don't need to add the prefix of the table it is automatically added by drupal in your case since you have placed it between {} it is adding another dot_ so the table name is becoming dot_dot_node instead of dot_node.

Note the relevant section from Drupal Database API documentation

> **Prefixing**
>
> In static queries, all table names must be wrapped in {}. That flags
>   them so that the database system can attach a prefix string to them if
>   appropriate. Prefixing allows for running multiple sites from the same
>   database or, in limited cases, for sharing selected tables between
>   sites.